# Como ler vários arquivos em TXT e salvar as strings em um NSArray?

Tags: array, ios, objective-c, arquivo, bundle

Explicação do cenário:

Ler o conteúdo de vários arquivos de extensão `.txt` e salvar as `strings` de cada arquivo separadamente em um `NSArray`, no caso, em cada índex do array.

Obstáculo: - São mais de 60 arquivos diferentes, embora o texto seja pequeno.
            - Possuem nomes diferentes Ex.: descDeVassoura.txt, descLampada.txt.

OBS: Eu já consegui um método para ler os arquivos e armazenar em uma `string`. Mas a problemática, é ler vários arquivos de uma única vez, e ter controle na ordenação em que são mantidos no `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quem estiver com este problema, de ter que ler vários arquivos com nomes diferentes, vc pode colocar os nomes deles como números e usar um looping for para apontar para cada um deles.

OU

Melhor proposta, é utilizar um banco de dados, no caso SQLite, recomendo o uso do framework Core Data para fazer o gerenciamento.